# How to order by in fetchAll() query

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm executing the following standard query in my repository (which works):

```
$objects = $this->findAll();
```

I need to order these objects by their name attribute. I wasn't lucky googling for this problem... Is there a simple way or do I need to make a custom query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->findBy(array("where_column", ""), array("order_column" => "desc/asc"));
```